# Error occur when i setup the IP of bbb-conf for bigbluebutton

Tags: installation, 10.04

```
techalay@ubuntu:~$ sudo bbb-conf --setip 192.168.0.75
[sudo] password for techalay: 
Assigning 192.168.0.75 for testing for firewall in /var/www/bigbluebutton/client/conf/config.xml
Assigning 192.168.0.75 for rtmp:// in /var/www/bigbluebutton/client/conf/config.xml
Assigning 192.168.0.75 for servername in /etc/nginx/sites-available/bigbluebutton
Assigning 192.168.0.75 for http:// in /var/www/bigbluebutton/client/conf/config.xml
Assigning 192.168.0.75 for web application URL in /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/bigbluebutton/WEB-INF/classes/bigbluebutton.properties
Assigning 192.168.0.75 for api demos in /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/demo/bbb_api_conf.jsp
Assigning 192.168.0.75 for record and playback in /usr/local/bigbluebutton/core/scripts/slides.yml
Restarting the bigbluebutton server ...
 * Stopping Red5 Server red5                                                              [ OK ] 
 * Stopping Tomcat servlet engine tomcat6                                                 [ OK ] 
Stopping nginx: nginx.
Killing: 4600
Stopping OpenOffice headless server.
Record and Playback monitoring stopped

Starting FreeSWITCH
Error: stacksize -1 is too large: run ulimit -s 240 or run /opt/freeswitch/bin/freeswitch -waste.
auto-adjusting stack size for optimal performance...
5553 Backgrounding.
Waiting for FreeSWITCH to start: ...........................
Starting OpenOffice headless server
Starting nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
nginx.
 * Starting Red5 Server red5                                                                      
                                                                                          [ OK ]
 * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat6                                                 [ OK ] 
Record and Playback monitoring started
Waiting for BigBlueButton to finish starting up (this may take a minute): .Startup unsuccessful: could not connect to 192.168.0.75 bigbluebutton api
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the developers of BigBlueButton.

What's happening is that the bash script bbb-conf is trying to run

```
wget http://192.168.0.75/bigbluebutton/api -O - --quiet
```

You can check this on the command line and should get

```
$ wget http://192.168.0.75/bigbluebutton/api -O -
<response><returncode>SUCCESS</returncode><version>0.8</version></response>
```

The wget is making an API call to BigBlueButton server (listening on port 80) get the current version of the API.  Can you check that the server's IP address is 192.168.0.75 and that port 80 is opened.

Comment: Hello Fred I get the same error when I try to open demo from my dev server. i.e. NoConfigFound .

 I tried the above command I do get return code as success there

$ wget http://10.0.2.15/bigbluebutton/api -O -
<response><returncode>SUCCESS</returncode><version>0.8</version></response>

In my config.xml I have set up the same IP i.e. 10.0.2.15. But I get NoConfigFound when I try to join the demo in the dev server

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be installing an older version of BigBlueButton.  Can you install the latest build of BigBlueButton 2.0-beta, see

http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.0/20install.html

and let us know if you encounter the same issue.  There are number of companies that are making heavy use of 2.0-beta in production, so its pretty solid.

--

Regards,... Fred

BigBlueButton Developer